# How can I specify filesystem rules?

Tags: sonarqube

I have the following two challanges:

1. I'd like to assert that the filename of an xml file is always equal to a certain string in the file itself
2. I'd like to assert that in every folder called 'Foo' is a file called 'bar.xml'

How can I do this with sonar? Is there already a plugin for this available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no plugin for that, you will have to write your own.

To do the first point, you can write a sensor that parses the XML files to find if the name of the files exists in the file itself, this should not be complicated.

For the second point, you would have to write a sensor that is executed only on folders.

You can check the ["Extension Guide" documentation](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/extension-guide.html) to find code samples on how to do that.